# Embedding layer output shape is 2D

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm encountering some issue with the output shape of my embedding layer, as per the keras documentation, the embedding layer should have an output shape of 3D tensor, but my embedding layer is only outputting 2D tensor.

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_matrix, max_length):
      super(MyModel, self).__init__()
      self.embedding_l1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                                                    output_dim=max_length, 
                                                    input_length=max_length,
                                                    weights=[embedding_matrix], 
                                                    trainable=False)
      self.bidirectional_l1 = Bidirectional(
                             tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(32, 
                                                                 return_sequences=False))
      self.dense_l1 = Dense(units=256, activation='relu')
      self.dropout_l1 = Dropout(rate=2e-5)
      self.dense_l2 = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, x):
      embedding_out = self.embedding_l1(x)
      print("SHAPE:",embedding_out.shape)
      bid_out1 = self.bidirectional_l1(self.reshape_l1(embedding_out))
      dense_out1 = self.dense_l1(bid_out1)
      drop_out1 = self.dropout_l2(dense_out1)
      dense_out2 = self.dense_l2(drop_out2)
      return dense_out2
```

It outputs the shape of the embedding layer out as a 2D (300,300) tensor. which causes error on the bidirectional lstm:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [300, 300]`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it's the input on the embedding layer. I didn't include a batch size so it looks like [batch_size, 300] for the input to the embedding instead of [,300].